# How to find density function of a 1D combinations of random variables which are defined in normally distributed vector?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have a normally distributed vector $(X,Y)$

$$(X,Y) \sim N\biggr[\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \biggr]$$

**TODO:** Find such measurable function $g(x)$ that minimize expectation
$$E[-24Y^{4} + 2g(X)Y^{2} + 2(g(X))^{2}+4] \longrightarrow min$$

**My attempt:** 
It's straightforward to notice that

$$E[-24Y^{4} + 2g(X)Y^{2} + 2(g(X))^{2}+4] = E[(Y^{4} + 2g(X)Y^{2} + 2(g(X))^{2})-25Y^{4}+4] = \\
= E[(Y^{2} + g(X))^2 + (4-25Y^{4})] = E[(Y^{2}+g(X))^{2}] + E[4-25Y^{4}]$$

Here we may consider only first term because second is a constant. So,

$$E[(Y^{2}+g(X))^{2}] = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} t^{2}f_{[Y^{2}+g(X)]}(t)dt$$

**Question:** 
And here I stumbled because I don't know how to detach random variables from random vector and find density function. I think that's technical task, but I don't know how to properly solve it.

PS: If you've found some mistakes in my steps - let me know, please.

Comment: I didn't check them, but based on your computations, you have $-g(X) = E(Y^2\mid X)$. This follows from the general result for $Z\in L^2$: $$E(Z\mid \mathcal F) = \mathrm{arg\,min}_{\tilde Z\in \mathcal F}E|Z-\tilde Z|^2$$

Comment: @AndrewZhang, thanks for hint to solve initial problem :)

Comment: I think you should be trying to minimize $E[(g(X)+Y^2/2)^2]$, meaning $g(X)=-(1/2)E[Y^2|X]$.